# getting 1004 error "No cells were found "when i find no cells after filter in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My problem is when I filter the records I get sometimes result as a no cells but im getting error as 1004 "no cells were found " i also used goto error method but it fails to perform.

I used bellow code

```
  If Error Then GoTo NoBlanks
           vfast_narecord = xlwkbOutput.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
On Error Resume Next
NoBlanks:
MsgBox "No cells were found!"
    Resume Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is

```
On Error GoTo NoBlanks
```

To disable the handler, use

```
On Error GoTo 0
```

as using `On Error Resume Next` will cause it to ignore all subsequent errors.

You also need to put your handler behind an `Exit Sub`/`Exit Function` or it will be executed every time. For example

```
    '...
    Exit Sub
NoBlanks:
    '...
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Few other options to your previous question that don't need filtering and counting visible cells:

- [`=AGGREGATE(3,3,A:A)`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) Excel function to count the number of cells in column A that are not empty, error, hidden, or `SUBTOTAL` / `AGGREGATE` function
- `=Count(A:A)` to count only cells containing numbers (including hidden cells but ignores errors)
- `=CountIf(A:A,#N/A)` to count cells containing `#N/A` error

All of those should be available with `WorksheetFunction` in VBA